# determine whether or not the second entry in each row converted to lower-case

Tags: python, csv, file

I have been doing these tasks:

1. Write    a   script that reads   in  the data    from the    CSV file    pastimes.csv located    in  the
   chapter 9   practice    files   folder, skipping    over the    header row
2. Display  each    row of data (except for the header row) as  a   list of strings
3. Add  code    to  your script to  determine   whether or not the  second  entry   in  each    row
   (the    "Favorite   Pastime") converted to  lower-case  includes    the word    "fighting" using
   the string  methods     find()      and     lower()

I have complited 2 of them but i really misunderstand the third one, cause my english is not very well and i really can't catch what do they want

```
import csv
with open("pastimes.csv", "r") as my_file:
    my_file_reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    next(my_file_reader)
    for row in my_file_reader:
        print(row)
```

Output: ['Fezzik', 'Fighting']

['Westley', 'Winning']

['Inigo Montoya', 'Sword fighting']

['Buttercup', 'Complaining']

Headers which i skipped: Person, Favorite pastime

Comment: Can you demonstrate your understanding of the question and ask a more specific question?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like:

```py
import csv
with open("pastimes.csv", "r") as my_file:
    my_file_reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    next(my_file_reader)
    for row in my_file_reader:
        print(row)
        if row[1].lower().find('fighting') >= 0:
            print('Second entry lowered contains "fighting"')
```